# How can i display all features from my dataset on my Mapbox map

Tags: mapbox

I have no coding experience but have been trying to create a web map for my organisation using Mapbox. I have a dataset that i have uploaded to my account that contains 15,789 point features. This all shows up fine in the dataset editor on my account however I am trying to use the following code to display and cluster the points on my map at lower zoom levels:

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource("mydata", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/{myusername}/{mydatasetid}/features?access_token={myaccesstoken}",
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14,
        clusterRadius: 120
    });
```

The styling of the points is all fine but only 1,864 of the points are showing up on the map - I need it to show all of them at once and I'm at a loss of how to do this! Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll breakdown the question for anyone reading:

> I am trying to use the following code to display and cluster the points on my map at lower zoom levels:

```
map.addSource("mydata", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/{myusername}/{mydatasetid}/features?access_token={myaccesstoken}",
    cluster: true,
    clusterMaxZoom: 14, 
    clusterRadius: 120  // this is the pixels per each point to be associated with a nearby cluster
});
```

by using `clusterMaxZoom`, from zoom level 0 - 14, the clustering behaviour will show, so you only need to edit the `clusterMaxZoom` option to allow clustering not to show past that zoomLevel.

i.e. if `clusterMaxZoom = 3` - then from a `zoomLevel` above 3 and upwards, clustering will not show and all points will be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your response. my problem is actually with the

data: "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/{myusername}/{mydatasetid}/features?access_token={myaccesstoken}",

line in the code. That call to mapbox's api only returns a subset of all the data contained in the data set. What it does return clusters fine but i need it to actually return all the results.

Comment: so you're saying by calling your dataset within mapbox - it returns a subset of the data....

Comment: Correct. The dataset is a made up of 15789 features but when i use the api it will only return some of those features, not all of them.

Comment: what is the return object/data response after you query the `dataset`?, 

i.e. what `api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1{myusername}/{mydatasetid}/featur‌​es?access_token={mya‌​ccesstoken}` - what does that return?

Comment: you may need to submit an issue to their tech support - https://www.mapbox.com/contact/support/#products/datasets

Comment: It returns a set of the data in geojson format (not sure how to upload a screenshot as a comment). I have tried their help but yeah, maybe I'll go down the support route. Thanks!

Comment: @dafyuk there's a limit to how much is given back...

*An extra note on dataset uploads: Multiple files can be uploaded to the same dataset without limit – they just need to be loaded 5 Mb at a time. The size of a dataset is unlimited, but the Mapbox Studio dataset editor can only display datasets of 20 Mb or smaller. These datasets can still be downloaded from Mapbox Studio and accessed through the Datasets API.*

Comment: `curl "https://api.mapbox.com/datasets/v1/{username}?access_token=your-access-token"` - and tell us the size of the dataset

Comment: Thanks for that. The original csv file I uploaded to create the dataset was 1.5 mb and the size in my mapbox account is 3mb so not sure why it would be a problem? It displays fine in the editor.

Comment: @dafyuk Running into the same problem currently, i wonder if you found a solution back then?